Should I give access to my work email
I am being forced out of the company that I technically own.
Unfortunately I agreed to put everything under my name when my partner (personal) was starting a business - against all my gut feelings.
Since the beginning things were off to a bad start.
It was no longer ours but his and turned into a terrible person who didn't even recognize anymore.
It was his idea and his clients from before , so I agreed that he was the main person in the company, although he never wanted to be a part of it legally in any way. (Fishy)
I've taken care of all the business startup tasks, put in the startup money, do all the admin, bookkeeping, accounting, payroll and also handle another part of the business while he does the actual main "job" part of the business and knows all the previous clients.
There's tons of details, which would take forever to tell
but my issue at this moment is... 3 years later he thinks I'm stealing money (which I'm not, we are just waiting to get paid... again... but he never listens to me) and now is "firing" me and wants access to my business email account and have it forwarded to his.
I don't want to give him access nor come across like I did something wrong to the clients.
I don't want to screw him over so bad that I just dissolve the company and walk away but I don't want to be screwed over either.

How does he fire you, if you own the company? You just go ahead and fire him, if he is  a source of problems. If everything is in your name, then is a nobody. Except maybe an employee.

And please write proper sentences with proper letter case. Also, please use punctuation marks. I corrected your text for now, but I do not want to do it again.

Close voter - this question is not asking for legal advice. The answer that the asker is looking for is that they need to seek legal advice. Please be helpful - you could have given this as an answer instead of asking everyone not to help.

@PlayerOne either the advice will be legal or based around the specific details for that company which we don't have...

@virolino - Ownership in a partnership is only as strong has the contract. The author themselves described the company as a partnership. Partnership normally has a very specific legal meaning in business.

@SolarMike Yes, but the OP didn't know that they needed to seek it. If they knew they wouldn't have asked this question.

@PlayerOne every question can be answered with „ask a lawyer“. I think this community is overdoing in closing interesting topics. Also I do not see how this community should not provide basic law advice. Everything workplace related has to do with some law. Law is also part of every serious busineds administration program.

@Sascha "Ask a lawyer" would actually be terrible advice for many questions here - it would be a waste of both the questioner and lawyer's time. Asking about the legal ramifications of things here is also clearly inappropriate. However asking for advice about a workplace situation that one needs advice on is the purpose of this site. Sometimes the answer is "you need legal advice". Telling someone they shouldn't have asked a question because the answer involves talking to a lawyer is absurd to me. I would not tolerate anyone reporting to me sabotaging others like that in my actual workplace.

@Donald: I re-read the question. You are right (I did not think about the contract that might exist between them), and I am right too (because OP has everything in his name). Lawyer it is then!

If he wants your business, he needs to formally buy it, or at least, he needs to buy you out. Whatever you do, do not give him the keys to the business, or the email, or anything, or he will be able to impersonate you and incur debt in your name. If he's unwilling to put the business in his own name, then you can't sell it/give it to him. Address that issue with him. Is he willing to put it under his name? Also, is he willing to make you an offer to buy you out?

Talk to a lawyer.
Everything's in your name. You own the company. It sounds to me like you have the power, but you need to talk to a lawyer in your local jurisdiction to confirm that, and then get their advice for what to do.
In the meantime, do not give over your access to anything.

If the company is in your name, then nobody can do legal things against you. Except maybe to sue you.
What you should do in this case, is difficult to estimate. Only you know all the details.

Should I give access to my work email

Definitely no. Especially considering that you are the owner. Your partner has no right to demand such things. If you do hand over the work e-mail (or any email), then all emails he will send in your name will be held against you.
EDIT: Additionally, you definitely need to talk to a lawyer you trust. (Tnx @PlayerOne for the answer)

Heck No - give no access to anyone without taking to a lawyer.
Having lived through several partners wigging out over the past few decades, it is unpleasant and highly disruptive to life. You will get through it. Keeping your head together now will help mitigate it.
First thing - and this can be a bit of a stretch. Imagine if you didn't have this partner. What would your goal be? Keep and growth this business? Move on to something else? Sale it and keep working there?
With a goal in mind and talking to a lawyer, now it is up to you.
Paying clients are a valuable thing.
Don't let a bully take away what is yours, if you still want it.

Unfortunately, the advice here is a mix between relationship advice and business advice. It's always a dumpster fire if you mix these two and things go south.
So, the underlying question is: how adversarial do you think this situation is, and how much more adversarial is it liable to get?
Unfortunately, mistrust often runs deeper than the current situation would indicate. It starts with accusations, it goes to asking for proof, it continues with you being asked perpetually to prove your innocence.
Also, you have to consider the angle that when your partner is asking for this level of control, he is basically running you out of the company -- with financial implications for your personal life, because at some point you would have no reason to draw a salary or any other sort of compensation from the company funds. After all, you are getting stripped of your duties.
IF you feel it is still possible, I would try mediation. Bring in an excellent outside accountant, or some audit company, that would make sure all the Is are dotted, all the Ts are crossed, no one is stealing, no one is doing things in a way that might be misused later.
On the other hand, my feeling is that your partner is indeed trying to run you out of the company. You may even begin mourning your relationship, at this point, because there is little to do when the person changes so much. Frankly, couples counseling sounds like something to try, aside from business mediation.
And don't forget the pointers already given in other answers: you are holding the keys, and you have the Nuclear Option to dissolve the company. Don't tip your hand.


I don't want to screw him over so bad that I just dissolve the company and walk away but I don't want to be screwed over either.

Which is understandable.
Given the animosity, you should absolutely not do anything that would reduce your current leverage, like giving him access to your email.
In fact, since you appear to be the sole legal owner, you do have the keys to the Nuclear Option. Now is probably a good time to at least appear as if you are willing to exercise that option.
